# Git rebase branch reapplying patch from master

Tags: git

I started to develop a new feature in master (patch "B"), made a push with it to upstream, and then decided that it needed to mature before staying in master. I branched ("newui") and reverted the new feature in master (patch "B'"). Now I want to rebase the newui branch to the tip of master without losing the "B" feature. Graphically, I want to go from:

```
    D-E [newui]
   /
A-B-B'-C [master]
```

To:

```
         B-D-E [newui]
        /
A-B-B'-C [master]
```

or:

```
    B-D-E [newui]
   /
A-C [master]
```

Answer (score 0):

Cherry-pick patch B onto master, then rebase newui onto master.

You can't collapse `A-B-B'-C` into `A-C` without rewriting history, which is usually a bad plan. (It could be done with `git rebase -i`.)

Comment: are you sure you mean to cherry-pick B onto *master*? it seems I must cherry-pick B onto newui...